# Как использовать новые геттер и сеттер?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Помогите пожалуйста отрефакторить код. Я написал компонент, который представляет из себя форму для отправки вопросов. Так же он выводит заданные на настоящий момент вопросы (пока в консоль, но это не принципиально). Вместо базы данных для учебных целей использую localstorage.

Итак, вот мой сервис, которые работает с "базой данных":

```
@Injectable()
export class QuestionsService {

    private questions: Question[];

  constructor() { 
    this.questions = localStorage.questions ? JSON.parse(localStorage.questions) : [];
  }

  getQuestions() {
    console.log('qqq');
    return this.questions;
  };  

  setQuestions(question): void {
    this.questions.push(question);
    localStorage.questions = JSON.stringify(this.questions);
  };    

}
```

Вот описанный тип:

```
export class Question {
    text: string;
    speakerId: number;
    dateHuman: string;
    dateUnix: string;
}
```

Вот компонент:

```
export class QuestionComponent implements OnInit {

  private questions: Question[] = [];

  constructor(private questionsService: QuestionsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {   
    this.getQuestions();
    console.log(this.questions);
  }   

  private sendQuestion(): void {   
    this.questionsService.setQuestions({
      "text": "42256yregd",
      "speakerId": 23,
      "dateHuman": "223 oct",
      "dateUnix": "22222"
    });
  };

  private getQuestions(): void {
    this.questionsService.getQuestions().map(question => {
      this.questions.push(question);
     });   
  };   

}
```

Эта система работает. Но мне хотелось бы использовать новые модные геттеры и сеттеры из стандарта es6. Вот моя попытка:

Сервис:

```
    private questions: Question[];

  constructor() { 
    this.questions = localStorage.questions ? JSON.parse(localStorage.questions) : [];
  }

  get questions() {
    console.log('qqq');
    return this.questions;
  };  

  set questions(question): void {
    this.questions.push(question);
    localStorage.questions = JSON.stringify(this.questions);
  };
```

компонент:

```
....
..

  private sendQuestion(): void {   
    this.questionsService.questions = {
      "text": "42256yregd",
      "speakerId": 23,
      "dateHuman": "223 oct",
      "dateUnix": "22222"
    };
  };

  private getQuestions(): void {
    this.questionsService.questions().map(question => {
      this.questions.push(question);
     });   
  };  

....
....
```

Но консоль выводит ошибку:

> Duplicate identifier 'questions'.

Comment: Я не помню, позволяет ли ES6 использовать в своей новой нотации названия геттеров и сеттеров, совпадающих с обрабатываемым свойством, но, руководствуясь здравым смыслом, вы возвращаете и внутри сеттера и внутри геттера `get` метод через замыкание. Чтобы этого избежать, храните вопросы внутри, например `_questions`. То есть имя свойства и методов должны различаться.

Comment: @smellyshovel, конечно не позволяет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема у вас вот в чем:

```
private questions: Question[];  // раз

get questions() { // два
set questions(question): void {
```

У вас объявлено два свойства с одним именем. Так нельзя делать, о чем вам и говорит tsc. Эта проблема решается добавлением префикса к приватному свойству:

```
private _questions: Question[];

get questions() {
set questions(question): void {
```

Answer (score 1):

Здесь

```
get questions() {
  ...
  return this.questions;
};
```

вы через замыкание рекурсивно вызываете геттер `questions`. До возвращения значения дело не доходит, потому как превышается максимальный стек рекурсивного вызова функции.

Интерпретатор понимает запись `this.questions` не как "обратись к *свойству* `questions` объекта `this`", а как "*получи значение* свойства `questions` объекта `this`". А получение значения происходит при помощи обращения к геттеру, который в данном случае имеет то же имя, что и само свойство `questions`, что и приводит к неверному результату (к "бесконечной" рекурсии). В конечном итоге вам выдается предупреждение об этом.

### Но.

Так **было бы**, если бы интерпретатор самостоятельно не пресекал подобное поведение. На самом деле до рекурсивного вызова дело даже не доходит, поскольку интерпретатор (компилятор) сразу обнаруживает, что у вас в коде коллизия имен - имя свойства совпадает с именем геттера.

В случае с сеттером, обращаясь внутри него к `this.questions` вы, опять же, обращаетесь не напрямую к свойству `questions`, а, из-за наличия геттера, сначала именно к нему [к геттеру]. Соответственно, по логике, и переопределяете вы тоже не свойство, а геттер.

Но, повторюсь, судя по ошибке, которую вы получили, подобное поведение все-таки как-то чем-то перехватывается. В ином случае мы бы, возможно, довольно долго гадали, в чем же дело. Ну или просто получили бы ошибку вроде описанной выше.

### Решение проблемы

В любом случае, ваша **проблема решается** путем разграничения имени свойства и его accessor'ов (геттеров и сеттеров). В идеальном случае стоит делать само свойство приватным, а геттер и сеттер - публичными. Но, поскольку ограничения доступа, как такового, EcmaScript не предусматривает (даже его 6-ая версия), то придется полагаться на добропорядочность тех, кто использует ваш код. **А именно**, дать *свойству* имя `_questions`, а getter'у и setter'у - просто `questions`.

Таким образом вы убиваете сразу двух зайцев: избавляетесь от нежелательного поведения и явно указываете, что само свойство является приватным (ну или защищенным).

Обращу ваше внимание, что, по-факту, вы можете использовать любое имя, а вариант с нижним подчеркиванием я привел в качестве наиболее правильно (по ряду причин, описанных выше).

Исходя из всего сказанного, ваши геттер и сеттер должны выглядеть как-то так (соответственно):

```
get questions() {
  console.log('qqq');
  return this._questions; // добавлено нижнее подчеркивание
};  

set questions(question): void {
  this._questions.push(question);
  localStorage.questions = JSON.stringify(this.questions);
};
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67715/discussion-on-answer-by-smellyshovel------).